# Back from a retreat: what to practice?

Tags: theravada, meditation-practicalities, meditation-recommendation, meditation, jhana

I need to give some background before I can ask my question so, my apologies for the long winded post.

I am back from a wonderful 6 days retreat (Bhikkhu Buddhadasa teaching/ Anapanasati). With the last 3 days of those in newly reached blissful state, working on exploring this sate and doing body scans to sharpen the mind further -and bring me back to earth- (as discussed with the instructor since I had previous experience with the Goenka method).

Since the retreat is over, I have spend some time reading about what happened to me (Rapture, Jhana, ...) as the dhamma talks did not covered this topic (it was a beginners retreat).

I can still focus my mind or have a quiet mind for some period of time, but, when I let go, I reach I very weak bliss state, if at all... (which I am OK with: I  have a lot to deal with in my life right now and only opportunity for 1 sitting a day in the early morning in poor conditions).

What should I use my little sitting meditation time doing?

I was thinking spending every second sitting doing metta meditation and the other one simply watching the beautiful breath (as defined by Ajahn Brahm), going back to body scan at later stage, when my life is a bit more in order and I have my own space to practice. Probably leaving my further investigations of Jhana for my next retreat...

Any advice or experience on this topic appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to practise alternate metta & breath meditation sounds ideal.

You correctly understand that the development of rapture & jhana generally require retreat conditions thus generally cannot be cultivated when there is limited time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your endorsement. It will help keep my doubts in check :)

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear you achieved certain steps in insight meditation during retreat. Your achievement will never go back if you continue mindfulness in every day living noting not detailed but grossly as when you eat , just "eat", when you walk" walk", or "move", when you touch water, "cold" or "hot", like that as simply doing as possible so that your concentration will surely help you at your short sitting meditation. All these concentration will surely lead to higher stage of insight meditation.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragements and advises. I will definitely keep doing this.